# How to crop in half a card image in bootstrap/css?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to cut in half this image and show that designed area in the card, here is a screenshot as a reference but I'm not quite sure how:

[image: Reference]

This is my code:

```
<div class="card">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="source" alt="icon">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h4 class="card-title">Card Title</h4>
    <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipsicing elit. Illo, quas.</p>
    <a class="btn btn-success btn-block" href="#">Read More</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use it as background and you can easily control what you want to show

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This uses the `object-fit` property. Caveat that this doesn't work in IE, but works in Edge. IF you need IE11 support, I can update the answer.

```css
.card img {
  /* change the height to whatever you want */
  height: 100px;
  object-fit: cover;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x800" alt="icon">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h4 class="card-title">Card Title</h4>
    <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipsicing elit. Illo, quas.</p>
    <a class="btn btn-success btn-block" href="#">Read More</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're welcome. You can also do a `background-image` as Temani suggested, you would just need another containing element instead of using the `img` element.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the link to codepen](https://codepen.io/yonasjonas/pen/jObGKVj)

Another elegant solution which I prefer is to add an image as CSS background-image. Then you have the full control displaying image in the div

just create add following CSS linked to  .card-img-top

```
  .card-img-top {
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nNO4.png);
    max-height: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    max-width: 600px;
    margin:auto;
    background-size:200px 400px ;
    background-position: 0px 40%;
    position:relative;
}
```

2 most important attributes are background-size and background-position

**background-size**  - specifies the size of the background image

**background-position** where first argument is x axis and second y axis